# Bit isn't on as expected

Tags: c#, bit

I'm converting a number to a `byte` array via the following method:

```cs
var bytes = new Span<byte>(new byte[4]);
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(bytes.ToArray(), <my-number>);
```

I'm then converting the `byte` array to a `BitArray` (for testing purposes).

```
var arr = new BitArray(bytes);
```

And testing to make sure the last bit is on (I'm using it as a flag).

```
Assert.True(arr[^1]);
```

However, this is returning false. This doesn't make sense to me, since my last `byte` in the array has a value of 29. Which, if I'm thinking correctly, would be `00011101` -- the last bit is on.

To further confuse me, if I use `WriteInt32*Little*Endian`, the bit at position 0 is on as I'd expect.

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm thoroughly confused as to why my last bit isn't on as expected.

EDIT: Supplied code in testable format, as requested.

```cs
var bytes = new Span<byte>(new byte[4]);
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(bytes, 1023773);
var arr = new BitArray(bytes.ToArray());
Assert.True(arr[^1]);
```

Comment: Don't you want : Assert.True(arr[0] & 1);

Comment: Can you write this example as if it were a unit test? Basically that exact same code but with `my-number` supplied?

Also try printing out the value of `arr` in binary?

Comment: @jdweng I don't think so? I just want to check the last bit.

Comment: @catfood Edited.

Comment: Note that your example unit test doesn't compile: there's no constructor to `BitArray` which takes a `Span<byte>`. Please test the code you put in your question!

Comment: Last bit or byte?  The variable arr is an array of 4  bytes.  You want to check one bit of the last byte.

Comment: @canton7 Fixed. My code is split out between multiple functions, so I was collecting it all into one place and just missed the ".ToArray()" in the return statement.

Comment: It's good to make a habit of pasting the code in your question into a new project / dotnetfiddle.net / etc, and making sure that it reproduces your issue! I've seen too many questions where the [mcve] didn't actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: @jdweng Both. Last bit of the last byte. So final element in the BitArray. canton's answer solved my question though.

Comment: Canton solution is looking at all four bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's worth checking the docs...

[For `BitArray(byte[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_BitArray__ctor_System_Byte___):

> The first byte in the array represents bits 0 through 7, the second byte represents bits 8 through 15, and so on.

So while you're getting big-endian bytes, the `BitArray` constructor is effectively little-endian: the least-significant byte is passed first.

This explains why `WriteInt32LittleEndian` performed as you expected: it produced the bytes in the same endianness that `BitArray` was expecting.

Comment: Ah, I did scan the docs but I was looking for the terms "BigEndian" and "LittleEndian", which I didn't see. Also was looking for a parameter to specify BigEndian, which I also did not see. Thanks!

Comment: The Remarks are always worth just reading through, in my experience. It doesn't take long